# Firefox transition -> translate

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, firefox

SO I'm using Bootstrap and I've got almost everything done but I can't get my carousel to have a transition on the caption. The transition on the carousel inner is working just fine but I want the caption to slide in from the top or bottom and fade in.
It's working in IE10/11 and Webkit. but the caption transition doesn't work in FF. It does work when I manually "start" the transition with Firebug i.e. clicking the opacity value on and off.
The only thing I've find thruw google-ing etc. is that u need to have the default values defined. So I triple checked that and I'm pretty sure all the default values are defined.
Anyone know why it's not working? I'm guessing I forgot to declare something?

PS: I've tried using different styles to transition but none of them worked (margin-top, top  and a few more). I'm using translate so the transition runs smooth on mobile phones/tablets.

Here's my carousel code:

```
/*== Carousel transition ==*/
.carousel-inner > .item {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: 1s ease-out -webkit-transform;   /* If the time is changed it also needs to be changed @ bootstrap.js -> line 359 */
    transition: 1s ease-out transform;
}
.carousel-inner > .item > img {
    width: 55%; /* Too make it fit next to side-items */
}
.carousel-inner > .item > .carousel-caption {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 340px);
    transform: translate(0, 340px);
    -webkit-transition-property: opacity, -webkit-transform;
    transition-property: opacity, transform;
    transition-duration: 0.5s, 0.6s;
    transition-timing-function: ease, ease-out;
    transition-delay: 0s, 0.5s;
}
.carousel-inner > .item > img,
.carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  line-height: 1;
}
.carousel-inner > .active,
.carousel-inner > .next,
.carousel-inner > .prev {
  display: block;
}
.carousel-inner > .active {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
    transform: translate(0, 0);
}
.carousel-inner > .active > .carousel-caption {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
    transform: translate(0, 0);
    opacity: 1;
}
.carousel-inner > .next,
.carousel-inner > .prev {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.carousel-inner > .next {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-150%, 0);
    transform: translate(-150%, 0);
}
.carousel-inner > .next > .carousel-caption {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 340px);
    transform: translate(0, 340px);
    opacity: 0;
}
.carousel-inner > .prev {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-150%, 0);
    transform: translate(-150%, 0);
}
.carousel-inner > .prev > .carousel-caption {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -340px);
    transform: translate(0, -340px);
    opacity: 0;
}
.carousel-inner > .next.left,
.carousel-inner > .prev.right {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
    transform: translate(0, 0);
}
.carousel-inner > .next.left > .carousel-caption,
.carousel-inner > .prev.right > .carousel-caption {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 340px);
    transform: translate(0, 340px);
    opacity: 0;
}
.carousel-inner > .active.left {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-150%, 0);
    transform: translate(-150%, 0);
}
.carousel-inner > .active.left > .carousel-caption {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -340px);
    transform: translate(0, -340px);
    opacity: 0;
}
.carousel-inner > .active.right {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-150%, 0);
    transform: translate(-150%, 0);
}
.carousel-inner > .active.right > .carousel-caption {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 340px);
    transform: translate(0, 340px);
    opacity: 0;
}
/*== Carousel transition ==*/
```

I've made a fiddle but I didn't get it working correcly: http://jsfiddle.net/Rudi91/sp3Nc/2/

Comment: Which element should use a transition? Did you post the right jsfiddle? This one does nothing but a hover-effect on the side arrows...

Comment: The text (caption) is suspose to fade and slide in from the bottom. And the image is suspose to slide out to the left and slide back in from the left.
But I can't seem to get it working in the fiddle (I've never made one before)

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's Javascript-based on your website, so you'll need to add that Javascript code into the JS-fiddle as well.

Comment: The transitions are actually pure CSS, I've included the bootstrap js and css. Bootstrap js changes the classes so the transitions will fire.
Might have done something wrong though, don't know exactly how jsfiddle works with external files

Comment: Looks like I forgot to select jQuery.... my bad. It's working now.
See the difference in Chrome and Firefox?

Comment: You need to update the jsfiddle link in your post (url changes automatically as you save on jsfiddle).

Comment: Ah thanks, didn't know. Updated it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking my code 20+ times and giving up I wen't on with the rest of the website. When I had to change the position of the carousel controls I noticed the left and right classes which I already had declared in my default stylesheet. Turns out u can't transition floating elements with Firefox, at least not perfectly.
Changed my left class to floatLeft and everything is working fine now.
So if anyone has a buggy transition in Firefox try checking if u got any floating elements and position them via an other method.